# Selecting documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to select documents that contain another document in elasticsearch grouped by id field.. I think it is more understable by the next example:

```
"doc1": {
   "id": "firstid"
   "my_field":"1"
}
"doc2": {
   "id": "firstid"
   "my_field":"12"
}
"doc3": {
   "id": "firstid"
   "my_field":"123"
}
"doc4": {
   "id": "secondid"
   "my_field":"1234"
}
"doc5": {
   "id": "firstid"
   "my_field":"12"
}
"doc6": {
   "id": "firstid"
   "my_field":"1"
}
"doc7": {
    "id":"firstid"
    "my_field":"qwerty" 
 }
 "doc8" {
     "id": "firstid"
     "my_field": "qwer"
  }
```

I want output to be

```
"doc3":{
   "id": "firstid"
   "my_field":"123"
 }
 "doc4": {
   "id": "secondid"
   "my_field":"1234"
}
 "doc7" {
   "id": "firstid"
   "my_field": "qwerty"
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I did not get your question. Do you want the result to have the documents that are first grouped by id and then the ones that have a unique my_field?

Comment: @pratikvasa Hi, I want to get documents which has same id and my_field must contain other my_fields of other documents with such id.

Comment: I may be wrong but this does not look like it can be done in a single query. Will think over it and let you know.

Comment: @pratikvasa thanks, i will wait:D